# Approximation of measured values with a function

Tags: approximation, mathematical-modeling

I'm trying to model a behavior of some computational methods. I've done some measurements and I have a following plot:

[image]

Is there any general strategy, how I could approximately describe this behavior with a function? Both curves should be the same one, just with one different input variable.

The model itself is supposed to predict time-consumption of the computational method, based on its basic settings, like type of decomposition (domains - processes, subdomains - threads) and the problem size.

Comment: With that shape I might try an exponential (do a semilogy plot and look for a straight line) and a power law (do a loglog plot and look for a straight line) fit.

Comment: If you provided a bit more context, perhaps one could also suggest a model based the specific situation. Since both axes are non-negative, a power law could be suitable, but maybe the specifics point to something else.

Comment: @String I've added some info into the question. The model is supposed to predict time-consumption of some computational method based on its settings (decomposition, size of problem etc.)

Comment: That seems to further support my guess.

Comment: @Ian And could you, please, show it more thoroughly in answer? I have no knowledge about power-law, so I'd really welcome it :-) So far I've only thought about exponential regression, but your idea is probably better...